# Are FMBL tabs still possible on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, fbml

Or they are dead now?

What is the next alternative for facebook tabs?

I want a HTML/PHP page using FMBL on my facebook page, but I am not sure if it is still possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FBML is deprecated, the "Static FBML" App is not available anymore.

You could try this now: https://www.facebook.com/staticHTML

I did not test it though, and the best way to create tabs is to create an app on your own:

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps

It´s not really hard to do, tabs are just iframes and you can program the pages like a real website. Just keep in mind that you need a server with SSL for canvas apps and tab apps.

Comment: what functionality do you need? why FBML?